# how to cover/repair nail holes on exterior window frame

Tags: windows, paint

we've just replaced our windows including exterior and interior frames/trims. The contractor told us they used oil-based primer and two coats of exterior paint, both are Benjamine Moore paint. However, after they've got the job done, I noticed lots of nail holes on the trims/frames. I can actually see the bare wood inside the holes. I've attached a close-up photo to show it. Because they are exterior frames/trims of the windows, I'm worried the water will go inside the wood, and window frames will get rotten quickly. Is there any remedy to fix this issue? Thanks a lot!
[image]

Comment: Epoxy should do the trick. Paint it with the leftover paint.

Comment: Hi @r13, what product do you refer to by using Epoxy? I know Expoxy glue. Do you mean to mix the Epoxy and left-over paint and paint the nail hold with it? Thanks.

Comment: It should be a two parts epoxy suitable for outdoor use. Do not mix epoxy with paint, but paint after filling the hole and after complete drying. https://www.amazon.com/J-B-Weld-8265S-Cold-Weld-Reinforced/dp/B0006O1ICE/ref=asc_df_B0006O1ICE/?tag=bingshoppinga-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=&hvpos=&hvnetw=o&hvrand=&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=e&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=&hvtargid=pla-4583863988772575&psc=1

Comment: Forgot to mention that for better result, you shall enlarge the hole intentionally to scratch the paint off the hole, to expose the base material, thus providing direct bonding between the epoxy and the base material.

Comment: Unacceptable craftsmanship. A competent window installer would lever leave those big divots. it should have been patched (with any number of products but I would have used exterior spackle) prior to being painted.

Comment: I agree with @JimmyFix-it. Call the contractor back and have him fix this. Should have been patched up _before_ the paint went on. If he has to sand back and repaint, it should be on his dime.